# Is it possible to use PhoneGap for only a few features in native Xcode4 project?

Tags: xcode, cordova

We are looking at building a cross-platform mobile app for iPhone, Android, etc.

In order to provide the best user experience on iOS, we are considering building native app in Xcode for iPhone, while using PhoneGap for all other platforms.

However there are a few features I would like to use the implementations my coworker is putting in PhoneGap.

Is it possible NOT to have a PhoneGap-based project in Xcode, but to still invoke calls to one or two PhoneGap functions?

I am new to mobile apps development, and very much appreciate your help!

Comment: WHat do you mean by this "Is it possible NOT to have a PhoneGap-based project in Xcode, but to still invoke calls to one or two PhoneGap functions?"

Comment: Hi Coder_sLaY, I meant to say "not having to use the PhoneGap project template". Caleb has pointed out that I wouldn't have to do so, and I will now dive into the code and wait for my "aha" moment.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely build an app that's mostly native, but uses PhoneGap for certain functionality. I'm not sure what you mean by "PhoneGap-based" -- you'll obviously need to include the PhoneGap code in your app, but you don't necessarily have to start your app using the project template that PhoneGap provides.

I'd suggest that you build a PhoneGap "hello world" type app -- basically, the simplest thing you can think of. Then take a few hours to step through it and really learn how PhoneGap does what it does. It's simpler than you might think, and you'll probably have an "aha!" moment or two. Once you understand what it's doing, you'll see how you can incorporate it into your own app.